# Spring Boot - Session timeout not working in 2.2.1 version

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, session, timeout

I am using Angular application and Spring boot Service. I need to force logout the user after period of inactivity is observed. So i have used the below property and it is not working.

**server.servlet.session.timeout=30s**

Can someone help on this ?

Comment: What kind of authentication mechanism you are using?

Comment: What isn't working? Session timeouts smaller then a minute generally don't work as servlet containers timeout sessions each minute (at least tomcat does). You are also using Angular which is client side and doesn't do anything on the server, so any activity on the client doesn't know about the server. If you are combining this with basic authentication then logout wo't work as for each request you are re-authenticating (that is how BASIC authentication works!).

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum. I understand that session timeout needs to be handled on the angular side. If there are any good examples, please let me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you haven't set the url to redirect once the session becomes invalid.

See ie:

```
http.sessionManagement().expiredUrl("/sessionExpired.html").invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html");
```

Check this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session) for a full view to spring security

As per the timeout `server.servlet.session.timeout` should do it.

Comment: I have added the expiredUrl too. And its not working